# Modify pixel art size without losing aesthetic

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, pixel, pixel-art

I have this platform of pixel art:

[image]

I want to modify its size to make it bigger, and I want to conserve the pixel-art aesthetic, like this:

[image]

But when I press Start to set the size, the piece turns fuzzy:

[image]

The idea is when I set the size, it gets the size of the 2nd image, not the 3rd picture.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While transforming, you should set your 'interpolation' to 'nearest neighbor'.

1. Select the layer your foreground is on;
2. Press <kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or choose <kbd>Edit > Free Transform...</kbd> to enter Free Transform mode;
3. In the option bar at the top of the screen, find the 'Interpolation' option and click the field after that to select the 'Nearest Neighbor' option;
4. Also in the options bar, set W and H sizes to 200% (or any integer * 100% value);
5. Press <kbd>Enter / Return</kbd>.

The default Interpolation setting is 'Bicubic Automatic', which will try and interpolate the enlarged image to prevent a blocky and pixelated look. That's great when you're working with photographic images, but for pixel art it's exactly that blocky look you are going for.

Comment: +1 or you can change the default image interpolation setting in Preferences > General, if you are going to be doing a lot of work like this - which would save having to change the interpolation method every time you do a transform.

Comment: Worked. Thank both of you for responses!